# c# Building dynamic linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List A` which has some properties.

Another `List B`
which has some properties.

Two booleans `bool c` and `bool d`.

I want to filter the List A based on some conditions like

```
a.type == b.type only if B.count > 0
and
a.IsSomeCondition only if c is true
and
a.IsSomeCondition only if d is true
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code of what you've attempted so far and where you got stuck? Do you have a list of links you've read during your research? How to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ArunYogeshwaran What you mean by word `Dynamic` ?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like this:

```
a = // some context;
if (b.Count > 0)
a = a.Where( //some filter );
if (c == true)
a = a.Where( //some filter );
if (d == true)
a = a.Where( //some filter );
```

Comment: But i dont want to apply filter on the same list again and again @VDN

Comment: if you are afraid that the new request will be sent to db again and again with each filter, than I think you should not. With this you are actually only preparing the query, but not querying the db. After you compile your query in such a way, you will send the request f.e with the command `var data = a.ToList();` @Arun